# AssetManager.php automatic deleted from cpanel

Tags: php, yii2

i have a cpanel host and i upload my site that written by yii2 advance to it.

after 3 or 4 days my cpanel automatic delete AssetManager.php from yiisoft\yii2\web\

until now about 5 times this is happen and i upload it again to abovementioned address.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question should be directed at the hosting provider.